# Addiling new mailchimp list with django

Tags: python, django, mailchimp

I have connected my django project to mailchimp list  with api and LIST KEY in order to get signals..Now I am willing to add an additional list to this function but it seems this is not working just separating with commas..Should I duplicate the function changing parameters or there is an easier way? thanks

```
class Newsletter (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    active = models.BooleanField (default =True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.active:
            return 'Subscribed'
        else: 
            return 'Unsubscribed'

def update_newsletter (sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print (instance.user)
    m = get_mailchimp_api()
    email = {'email': instance.user.email}
    if not instance.active:
        m.lists.unsubscribe('**LIST_ID**',  email , 
            delete_member= False)
    else:
         m.lists.subscribe('**LIST_ID**', email , 
            double_optin= False,
             update_existing = False, 
             send_welcome = False)

post_save.connect (update_newsletter, sender = Newsletter)
```

Comment: where is your list?  Your question is not clear as to what your problem is, or what you want to add

Comment: Hello, I have a function to get signals from users who subscribe or unsubscribe. This function belongs to a list idesntified as LIST_ID. I need to add a new list...Can I do it in the same function adding the new LIST ID somewhere, or should I create a new function for it? Thanks for your assistance